# Direct file upload using Ajax or JQuery (with or without a form)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, file-upload, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use the second "Direct file upload" method described at the end of the page here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaFileUpload

How do I implement the required Ajax/Jquery/Js function that will allow me to use this?  Can anyone please provide some hits or snippets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. At least not in browsers that do not support the HTML5 [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). For those browsers you could use some existing file upload control such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), [Blueimp File upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/), [Valums File Uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader), ...

Those controls detect whether the browser supports the File API and it will use it. If it doesn't it will use other techniques such as using hidden `<iframe>`, `Flash`, `Silverlight`, ...